# API VK account.lookupContacts Access denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, get

не могу получить информацию по запросу VK API

```
`https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxx #ид приложения
&scope=friends,offline
&display=page
&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html
&response_type=token
&v=5.92`
```

получаю токен далее делаю:

```
`https://api.vk.com/method/account.lookupContacts?contacts=номер_телефона&service=phone&return_all=0&fields=photo_50,photo_100&v=5.92&access_token=token`
```

Ошибка:  Access denied

Answer (score 1):

account.lookupContacts - закрытый метод, доступ к которому есть только у разрешенных мобильных клиентов (в разделе /dev на сайте он тоже скрыт)

Выполнять его так же можно только передавая параметр 'sig' - md5 подпись от строки с методом, всеми параметрами и SECRET кодом, который выдает api при авторизации. Доступ к ней тоже есть только у авторизованных мобильных клиентов, вроде ВКонтакте для Android, Kate Mobile и других.

Самый простой способ обойти запрет доступа - достать эти данные из мобильного клиента и выполнять запрос с ними.

Comment: а по подробнее можно? в виде прямых запросов или как быть?